# CloudFormation: conditional parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Building a CloudFormation stack template, I have a setup constellation where upon instantiation I want to reference either the name of another CloudFormation stack *or* a non-CloudFormation-managed database as a parameter.

Is there a way to represent this constellation in my template? I.e. "Parameter `DatabaseHost` is mandatory if Parameter `DatabaseStack` is blank"?

Comment: I don't believe so. You could make both optional, but add commentary that the user must provide one or the other. Or have two templates.

Comment: thank your for checking. I had hoped to not need two templates but since I'm using a Ruby DSL, it might be the best approach since I can just as well share some Ruby code and avoid the duplication that would come from having two completely separate JSON-based stacks. Feel free to post this as an answer, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a native option in CloudFormation to make one template parameter conditional on a second template parameter.

Possible workarounds might be:

- make both optional, and tell user to supply one of them
- use two templates, one for each of the two use cases
- programmatically generate your template *after* asking the user for parameters

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it wasn't possible at the time of the question, but now, you can include conditions on a CloudFormation template. See [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html).

In this example, I use one value or another depending on the environment:

```
InfrastructurePipelineStack:
Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
Properties:
  TemplateURL: !Sub "https://<masked>.yml"
  Parameters:
    ProjectName: !Ref ProjectName
    ...
    LambdaNotifications: !If [isDev, !GetAtt NotificationsStack.Outputs.LambdaNotifications, !Ref LambdaNotifications]
```

If the environment is Development ("isDev" condition), I use the output of other CloudFormation Stack as the value. If not, I use a provided fixed value (non-CloudFormation value).

In this case "isDev" is acting as "parameter DatabaseStack is blank" in the OP question.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an example of making CloudFormation attribute conditionally used, based on some defined condition. Below is an example and source of AWS Cloud Formation documentation I took it from.

```yaml
    Parameters:
      DBSnapshotName:
        Description: The name of a DB snapshot (optional)
        Default: ""
        Type: String
    Conditions:
      UseDBSnapshot: !Not [!Equals [!Ref DBSnapshotName, ""]]
    Resources:
      MyDB:
        Type: "AWS::RDS::DBInstance"
        Properties:
          AllocatedStorage: 5
          ...
          DBSnapshotIdentifier: !If [UseDBSnapshot, !Ref DBSnapshotName, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
```

source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-sample-templates.html